# Is it enough to Unpublish a non-compliant app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have multiple apps in my Google Play console and one of the app is very old like 5years, and I didn't updated it since then. It uses Location services in background, so under the "Sensitive permissions and APIs" I have to declare that this app uses background location, but there is also a requirement for "Prominent Disclosure" which must be done within the app itself. As my app was built on old SDK's and libraries, and I've no intention to keep this app active under play store, if I just want to put this "Prominent Disclosure" I would have to update many things to meet current minimum requirements of play store to publish newer version, which is basically time wasting and useless for me. Total user base is also only 3 users.

First I thought to remove this app from my account, but there is no way to do so and we can apparently only "Unpublish" app, which I've already done so.

**So is it enough to keep this app "Unpublished" without worrying if Google may suspend my whole account and rest of apps just because of this app? Because other apps in my account has thousands of users.**

Comment: unpublishing an app won't be against any policies and terms of usage as far as I know so unless any of your other apps are not in compliance with google developer policies nothing will happen to your account

Comment: Thanks. You might want to write as an answer so I can mark it as approved.

Answer (score 0):

unpublishing an app won't be against any policies and terms of usage as far as I know so unless any of your other apps are not in compliance with google developer policies nothing will happen to your account